# Fetching respective group values in a regex expression

Tags: python, regex

I have an example string like below:

```
Handling - Uncrating of 3 crates - USD600 each     7%=126.00        1,800.00
```

I can have another example string that can be like:

```
Unpacking/Unremoval fee     Zero Rated        100.00
```

I am trying to access the first set of words and the last number values.

So I want the dict to be

```
{'Handling - Uncrating of 3 crates - USD600 each':1800.00}

or 

{'Unpacking/Unremoval fee':100.00}
```

There might be strings where none of the above patterns (Zero Rated or something with %) present and I would skip those strings.

To do that, I was regexing the following pattern

```
pattern = re.search(r'(.*)Zero.*Rated\s*(\S*)',line.strip())
```

and then

```
pattern.group(1)
```

gives the keys for dict and

```
pattern.group(2)
```

gives the value of 1800.00. This works for lines where Zero Rated is present.

However if I want to also check for pattern where Zero Rated is not present but % is present as in first example above, I was trying to use | but it didn't work.

```
pattern = re.search(r'(.*)Zero.*Rated|%\s*(\S*)',line.strip())
```

But this time I am not getting the right pattern groups as it is fetching groups.

Answer (score 0):

Sites like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) can help debug regexes.

In this case, the problem is with operator precedence; the `|` operates over the whole of the rest of the regex. You can group parts of the regex without creating additional groups with `(?:  )`

Try: `r'(.*)(?:Zero.*Rated|%)\s*(\S*)'`

Definitely give [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) a go, though, it'll show you what's going on in the regex.

Comment: the problem is it is working for Zero Rated lines. But for lines where I have %, it is fetching  wrong value. For ex if text is 


 Delivery Cartage - IT Equipment, up to 1000kgs -                                                                                   7%=210.00                         3,000.00

It is giving 

{'Delivery Cartage - IT Equipment, up to 1000kgs -                                                                                   7': '=210.00'}

It should be 3000.00 as value and key also should not have the 7 it is fetching from second part

Comment: Try it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), it explains your regex and shows you which parts of the text match which group. Maybe you want `(.*)(?:Zero.*Rated|\d+%=[\d.]+)\s*(\S*)` but probably you want to fine-tune it until it does what you need.

Comment: I am able to work it for just zero rated lines. That part I have got with existing ones. But its the % lines which it's not picking up.

Answer (score 0):

You might use

```
^(.+?)\s*(?:Zero Rated|\d+%=\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})*\.\d{2})\s*(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2})
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `(.+?)` Capture **group 1**, match any char except a newline as least as possible
- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace chars
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `Zero Rated` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `\d+%=` Match 1+ digits and `%=`
  - `\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})*\.\d{2}` Match a digit format of 1-3 digits, optionally repeated by a comma and 3 digits followed by a dot and 2 digits
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace chars
- `(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2})` Capture **group 2**, match the digit format

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6OlU5H/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/aK9GV7)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"^(.+?)\s*(?:Zero Rated|\d+%=\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})*\.\d{2})\s*(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2})"
test_str = ("Handling - Uncrating of 3 crates - USD600 each     7%=126.00        1,800.00\n"
            "Unpacking/Unremoval fee     Zero Rated        100.00\n"
            "Delivery Cartage - IT Equipment, up to 1000kgs - 7%=210.00 3,000.00")

print(dict(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)))
```

Output

```
{'Handling - Uncrating of 3 crates - USD600 each': '1,800.00', 'Unpacking/Unremoval fee': '100.00', 'Delivery Cartage - IT Equipment, up to 1000kgs -': '3,000.00'}
```